# Is there any way to apply style to span based on content using SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

The purpose is to apply `css` style to a `span` element using only dynamic `SASS` style processor and without any `javascript/jQuery.`

The condition for applying style should be the **text** inside the `span`.

Example:

```html
<span>Should be green</span>
<span>Just span</span>
<span>Just span</span>
<span>Just span</span>
<span>Just span</span>
<span>Just span</span>
```

While researching I did not find any solution.

I know that there are ways to set it simply by using jQuery or JS, but my requirement is to find solution in sass style.

Thank's for any advice !

Comment: If the number of spans is known you can use [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Comment: @Ihazkode it is unknown for sad. Just one thing may be used for identification is the text inside the span

Comment: In that case you're out of luck because CSS works based on nodes and not based on the contents of the node. You need to use script here.

Comment: @Ihazkode sad, but seems like that yeah. Thanks man !

Answer (score 1):

You just add a div or class ex:-  
and give the css to all the span.

```css
.demo-class span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.demo-class span:nth-of-type(1) {
      color: #008000;
}
.demo-class span:nth-of-type(2) {
      color: #7a73aa;
      font-size: 20px;
}
.demo-class span:nth-of-type(3) {
      color: #ea5f72;
      font-size: 15px;
}
.demo-class span:nth-of-type(4) {
      color: #f1cb06;
}
.demo-class span:nth-of-type(5) {
      color: #7a73aa;
      font-size: 15px;
}
.demo-class span:nth-of-type(6) {
      color: #f1cb06;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-class">
  <span>Should be green</span>
  <span>Just span</span>
  <span>Just span</span>
  <span>Just span</span>
  <span>Just span</span>
  <span>Just span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's seems to be a good point, thanks !